How to set up a CI/CD pipeline for your iOS app using Fastlane and GitHub Actions fetching issue?
the issue for profile matching and target unable

Couldn't automatically detect the provisioning profile mapping

Since Xcode 9 you need to provide an explicit mapping of what

provisioning profile to use for each target of your app

[Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (60).


==> issue for errors <==
Build The app
Unable to open base configuration reference file '/Users/runner/work/V2-iOS-YourProjectName/V2-iOS-YourProjectName/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-YourProjectName/YourProjectName.staging.xcconfig'. (in target 'YourProjectName' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-YourProjectName/Pods-YourProjectName-frameworks-Staging-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'YourProjectName' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-YourProjectName/Pods-YourProjectName-frameworks-Staging-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'YourProjectName' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-YourProjectName/Pods-YourProjectName-resources-Staging-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'YourProjectName' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-YourProjectName/Pods-YourProjectName-resources-Staging-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'YourProjectName' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
No profiles for 'com.YourProjectName.app.notificationservice' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.YourProjectName.app.notificationservice'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'NotificationService' from project 'YourProjectName')
Build The app
Process completed with exit code 1.
